# Java Generics, is <C> equal to <T>?

Tags: java, generics

If I had a Java generic class of...

```
public class EntityStuff<C> extends AbstractPropertyStuff<C> implements Serializable {

}
```

Is this the same as...

```
public class EntityStuff<T> extends AbstractPropertyStuff<T> implements Serializable {

}
```

does the letter hold any significance?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

No, there is no significance.

There are conventions (see [Java Generics Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html)):

```
E - Element (used extensively by the Java Collections Framework)
K - Key
N - Number
T - Type
V - Value
S, U, V etc. - 2nd, 3rd, 4th types
```

Answer (score 10):

It's exactly the same, letter doesn't hold any significance. In fact, the type parameter can be any valid Java identifier, so:

```
EntityStuff<T>
EntityStuff<t>
EntityStuff<TTT>
EntityStuff<ttt>
EntityStuff<_t23>
```

are all legal.

Answer (score 3):

`C` and `T` are just variable names. They should not be Java keywords, but otherwise, they don't have any special meaning to the compiler.

Comment: They also shouldn't match other class names - this has caused some confusion in the past...

Answer (score 2):

The `T` or `C` is just the identifier for the type parameter, and so those statements are the same.

You can use other, more meaningful, identifiers like `TResult` or  `TModelType`  to make it more expressive and indeed I would encourage you to do so, especially if you have more than one type parameter.

Answer (score 0):

No, the letter is just the name of the type parameter. It doesn't matter what letter you use. In fact, it doesn't have to be just a single letter, you could use a longer name if you want; using a single letter for type parameters is just a convention.

Answer (score 0):

No - the type parameter's name is of no significance

Answer (score 0):

Both the same.  The letter can be a word, but you will find using T for type and K for key and V for value (etc.) makes for easier reading.